# Error Message when completing two way ANOVA on SPSS

Tags: spss

I am attempting to complete a two way ANOVA on SPSS but I am receving the following error message "Unrecoverable application error in the statistics processor". It is then not showing me any of the results. Any help or suggestions of how to resolve this would be very much appreciated. Thank you

I have contacted my university and IBM direct who have both said they are unable to help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What version of SPSS are you using ? Are you doing it via syntax or via the menu ? Can you post the syntax you are using, or the log which is displayed in the output ?

Comment: Also, have you tried this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/452772/unrecoverable-application-error-in-the-statistics-4/

Answer (score -2):

Try obtaining the newest FixPack (https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/). It may resolve the "Unrecoverable application error in the statistics processor" error message.